# Is there a responsive layout manager that support overlapping

Tags: java, swing, overlap

I'm trying to create a library program that scans a local directory for some files and then present them with their thumbnails and titles. I've tried multiple layout managers but couldn't get the results I want with any.

Basically what I want is to have a responsive grid that repositions cells depending on the window size

[image]

[image]

This effect is already possible with Flow Layout or [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), But the other thing is I also want to resize individual cells when clicked and overlap the one under

[image]

The closest thing I could think of that use this mechanism is the windows 10 desktop

[image]

[image]

So is it possible to achieve this effect using any layout manager?

Comment: You can somewhat simulate this effect by overlaying your cell with a slightly larger or much larger JDialog.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve the behavior that you desire.
I chose to use [popup menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup).

The below code is just a *proof of concept* (POC). I hope that it will be enough to help you complete your application according to your requirements. The below code is a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can copy the code as is and compile it and run it.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Overlaps extends MouseAdapter implements Runnable {
    private Icon  largeIco;
    private Icon  smallIco;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPopupMenu  popup;

    public Overlaps() {
        Class<?> thisClass = getClass();
        URL url = thisClass.getResource("11-cd-32px.png");
        smallIco = new ImageIcon(url);
        url = thisClass.getResource("11-cd-64px.png");
        largeIco = new ImageIcon(url);
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.MouseAdapter
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        Component cmpt = event.getComponent();
        popup.show(cmpt, -10, -10);
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(String text) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text, smallIco, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        label.addMouseListener(this);
        return label;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("Zero"));
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("One"));
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("Two"));
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("Three"));
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("Four"));
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("Five"));
        mainPanel.add(createLabel("Six"));
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void initPopup() {
        popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add(new JLabel(largeIco));
    }

    private void showGui() {
        initPopup();
        frame = new JFrame("Example Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Overlaps());
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I launch the application.

[image: launched]

And this is how it looks with the popup showing.

[image: popup showing]

Comment: I can work with that, but is there a way to keep the JPopupMenu from disappearing when resizing the window or clicking outside it?